# Spring Boot REST custom request parameters mapping for complex abstract entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working on REST API for the application using SpringBoot 2 and I want to get a specific object as my request parameter. Assuming I have my endpoint declared like this:

```
@RestController("TestEndpoint")
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
    String getTest(MyWeirdRequest myRequest) {
        return myRequest.toString();
    }
}
```

where MyWeirdRequest looks like this:

```
public class MyWeirdRequest {
    private Map<String, String> startWithOne;
    private Map<String, String> anythingElse;

    // setters and getters here 
}
```

and my GET request would look like this example:

```
http://localost:8088/test?first=aaa&second=1bbb&third=1ccc&fourth=2ddd
```

List of parameters is not defined anywhere and so they can contain any keys.
I want my endpoint to get `MyWeirdRequest` object where all the params with value starting with 1 to be in startWithOne map and the rest of params to be in anythingElse where key is request parameter name. So in case of request above I want the result where my endpoint receives a MyWeirdRequest containing

```
startWithOne=[second:1bbb, third:1ccc]
anythingElse=[first:aaa, fourth:2ddd]
```

I know I could use a Map as a `getTest` param and then do all the mapping inside this method, but `MyWeirdRequest` will be used as a param for multiple endpoints and I want to avoid working with Maps directly everywhere.

I tried to create a custom PropertyEditor and register it in WebDataBinder, but it is only used if there is a @Requestparam annotation, but if I add it to `getTest` method - a parameter named myRequest becomes mandatory.

How do I handle the request like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that in case you need to parse request parameters as I needed - you should implement [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html). It provides the ability to access a lot of different request data. In my case it could look like this (initially I've forgot that request parameters may contain arrays of values, so `MyWeirdRequest` field types were changed to `Map<String, String[]>`):

```
    public class TestArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(MyWeirdRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory)
            throws Exception {
        MyWeirdRequest result = new MyWeirdRequest();
        Map<String, String[]> startsWithOne = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String[]> anythingElse = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> paramEntry : webRequest.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            String[] swoValues = Arrays.stream(paramEntry.getValue()).filter(v -> v.startsWith("1"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
            if (swoValues.length > 0) {
                startsWithOne.put(paramEntry.getKey(), swoValues);
            }
            
            String[] aeValues = Arrays.stream(paramEntry.getValue()).filter(v -> !v.startsWith("1"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
            if (aeValues.length > 0) {
                anythingElse.put(paramEntry.getKey(), aeValues);
            }
        }
        result.setStartWithOne(startsWithOne);
        result.setAnythingElse(anythingElse);
        return result;
    }

}
```

After that, I created a configuration to register my request resolver:

```
@Configuration
public class TestRequestConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new TestArgumentResolver());
    }
    
}
```

And that's pretty much it!